# Why is the code giving Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

```
int *f1(int i) {
    return &i;
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    int *p = f1(x);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Even if I write

```
int *p;
    p = f1(10);
```

This still gives segmentation fault.

Can somebody explain, Why is the code not working ?

Comment: The address of parameter `i`, returned by `f1` is invalid as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the address of `i`, which only exists until `f1` returns. Once `f1` returns, `i` ceases to exist, and the pointer you created is no longer usable. Dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Maybe you wanted

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *f1(int i) {
   int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p = i;
   return p;
}

int main(void) {
   int *p = f1(10);
   printf("%d\n", *p);
   free(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sami You can use static memory allocation method too. Please check it.

Comment: @Krishna Kanth Yenumula, I can't imagine a situation where you'd want to do that.

Comment: @ikegami Please check my answer below.  We can use it in the above situation ( mentioned in question).

Comment: @Krishna Kanth Yenumula, I've seen your answer. And I know it works (with some pretty massive limitations). But I can't imagine a situation where you'd want to do that

Comment: @ikegami What is the limitation??  Can you please explain or provide some links

Comment: @Krishna Kanth Yenumula, Added on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `static allocation` or `dynamic allocation` depends on the problem situation.

**Scenario for `static allocation`** : Let's say, we need to find number of times a function has been called. Then we need a single variable, whose value should be updated and retained across function calls. If we use `dynamic allocation` here, new variable will be created for each function call and you cannot track the value across function calls. `Dyanmic allocation`  will not work here. You will end up wasting a lot of memory, if the number of fuunction calls are high.

**Scenario for `dynamic allocation`** : Suppose, you want to create a new variable for every functional call, then we can use `dynamic` .

**Note :** If we call the function 100 times, there will be only one static variable used for all the 100 times. But, in case of `dynamic allocation` 100 new variables will be created. So, we should use them according to situation.

The lifetime of static variables is entire duration of the program's execution. Variable `i` lifetime ends at the end of the `f1` function. To extend its lifetime, we can use static memory allocation or dynamic memory allocation (using `malloc`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int *f1(int i) {
   static int p; //value will be retained between function calls.
   p = i;
   return (&p);
}

int main(void) {
   int *p = f1(10);
   printf("%d\n", *p);
   printf("%d\n", *p);
   return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
10
10
```

Comment: No, you stored the address of `i` into `p`, so the function still returns an address that is invalid when the function returns.  It is still undefined behavior, even if the undefined behavior seems to be correct

Comment: Since p is static, the address will be retained. I checked in my system.  It worked. Please check.

Comment: The address still points to where 10 was stored on the stack during the function call because you haven’t called any other functions to mess the stack up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224911/discussion-between-krishna-kanth-yenumula-and-ikegami).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you. I was wrong. I understood my mistake. I modified my answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I deleted the image.